# RESTAPINotEnabledForComponentSharedMailbox error

Tags: outlook, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I have users that cannot use our services because Outlook REST API returns the following error code `RESTAPINotEnabledForComponentSharedMailbox`.

It looks like their mailbox is not a shared mailbox. So what kind of mailbox is that?

Can you tell me more about this error? Is there something we can do?

Comment: We believe this is a case where the user's mailbox isn't in the cloud, so the REST API can't access it. Is this user's mailbox maybe in an on-premises Exchange server?

Comment: Ok so it means that they were using Azure Ad for login but not Outlook Online for mailing, right? To your knowledge is there a way to check this 'for sure'.

Comment: If you can post some response headers from a response where you get this error I can see if we can determine from our logs.

Comment: I will try to do that thanks !

Comment: Were you able to find an answer for a definitive way to know that is going on?
I see this error a lot and i don't know what to make of it :/

Comment: Now I'm also face same issue,Could you  Please explain briefly how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

This means user doesn't have their mailbox in O365 cloud. This can mean that their mailbox is either on premises or they don't even have any mailbox. You should use auto discover to get the right end point to connect.

Comment: Now I'm also face same issue,Could you  Please explain briefly how to fix that?

Comment: There is no issue. The mailbox you are trying to access is not in O365 cloud. Use auto discover to figure out where the mailbox is.